# Passing variable to view by with not working in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, view, controller

I want to pass my variable to view by `with`
this is my controller for example :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Prices ;

class PricesController extends Controller
{

        function getIndex()
        {
            $prices =   Prices::orderBy( 'id' , 'desc' )-> paginate(2) ;

            return view('home')->nest('content' , 'price', compact('prices')  )   ->with( [ 'title' => 'prices page' , 'message' => 'my message text ' ]) ;

        }
}
```

and this is my `master.blade.php` :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fa">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>    {{ $title  }}</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url()  }}/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url()  }}/css/style.css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>

    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    @yield("main")
</div><!-- container -->



<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->

<script src="{{ url()  }}/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ url()  }}/js/dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="{{ url()  }}/js/collapse.js"></script>
<script src="{{ url()  }}/js/transition.js"></script>
<script src="{{ url()  }}/js/tab.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is `home.blade.php` :

```
@extends('master')

@section('main')
    @include('top_menu')

    <div class="row">
        <section class="col-sm-12 col-md-12   content">

            <div class="row">
                <section class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="in">
                        {!! $content !!}
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>

        </section>
    </div>


@stop
```

and this is my `price.blade.php` :

```
@if(   empty($prices)     )
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
        No result
    </div>
@else


    @if( !   isset(  $message)     )
            No message
    @else
        {{ $message  }}

        @endif

    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>yeat</th>
            <th>qnty </th>
        </tr>

    @foreach( $prices as $price )
        <tr>
            <td>  {{$price->product}} </td>
            <td>  {{$price->yaer}} </td>
            <td>  {{$price->quantity}} </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </table>

    <center>    {!! $prices->render() !!} </center>


@endif
```

in Output `title` in     `<title>    {{ $title  }}</title>` in `master.balde.php`
is passed good and it will  show : ***prices page*** in page title , But in this part in `price.blade.php`  :

```
@if( !   isset(  $message)     )
        No message
@else
    {{ $message  }}

    @endif
```

the output is :

> No maessage

I can access to `$message` and `$title` in `home.blade.php` , But no in `price.blade.php`

how can I fix it ?

Comment: You're passing the key `message` to the view and then you're trying to use the `$maessage` variable name, notice the extra "**a**" in "m**a**essege".

Comment: it was just a mistak while I was typing question , I edited it ,I still have the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in a word - `maessage`, maybe you sending `message`, but trying to use `maessage`. Please check it.

Update:

Your code now looks fine. However, look at `@if (empty($prices))` part. If `(empty($prices)` returns `true`, your code with `$message` part will never be executed. Probably that's why you don't see `my message text`.

Update 2:

```
return view('home')
    ->nest('content', 'price', array(
        'prices' => $prices,
        'title' => 'prices page',
        'message' => 'my message text'
        ))
    ->with([ 'title' => 'prices page', 'message' => 'my message text']);
```

Comment: it was just a mistak while I was typing question , I edited it ,I still have the problem

Comment: I've just tried your code and it works. I think you had a problem with wrong spelled variable (you copy-pasted it here). Please double check both `home.blade.php` and your controller. Also, please read Update in my post.

Comment: I did not  copy-paste exact code here at first time , but now this is exact code ! For Your Update , I know and  this is ok !

Comment: I can access to $message and $title in home.blade.php , But no in price.blade.php

Comment: Oh, there was no this information in original question. In that case please look at Update 2 in my post. I hope this code should work for you.